# Looking for help unlocking information in this .db file

Tags: sqlite

I am looking for some help, as this world is pretty foreign to me. The company I work for has security cameras that were set up by a previous employee. I am needing to get in to the program to change some things for the owner, but do not have the password. The password she has written down does not work.

Anyways, I went poking around in a couple .db files that we have used for exporting/importing settings between machines for this program and found a line for UserPwd, but it is "encrypted"? Or maybe that is not the name for it.

What I am looking for is how to convert this to plain text, if possible. And if I am in the wrong place, feel free to let me know. Below is the copy of the .db

```
SQLite format 3######@  ###j###############f##############################################################—####<#¦#ì#Ý#â#Ó#ö#Ø#É#Î#¿#Ä#µ#«#°#º#ñ#¡#û#ç#œ#—############################################################################################################################################P###+
+#Ytablesqlite_sequencesqlite_sequence#CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)…
#######‰atableTMatrixTMatrix#CREATE TABLE TMatrix(
    Lsh INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,----¾ØÕóÁ÷Ë®ºÅ£¬Ö÷¼ü
    Lsh_Dom INTEGER,-----¾ØÕó×ÓÓòÁ÷Ë®ºÅ
    GlobNum INTEGER,-----¾ØÕóµÄÈ«¾Ö±àºÅ
    LocalNum INTEGER,-----¾ØÕóµÄ¾Ö²¿±àºÅ
    MatrixName VARCHAR(64),-----¾ØÕóÃû³Æ
    UserName VARCHAR(64),-----µÇÂ¼¾ØÕóµÄÕÊºÅÃû³Æ
    UserPwd VARCHAR(64),-----µÇÂ¼ÃÜÂë
    DeviceIP VARCHAR(64),-----¾ØÕóµØÖ·
    GateWay VARCHAR(64),-----Íø¹ØµØÖ·
    Port INTEGER, -- ¶Ë¿ÚºÅ----µÇÂ¼¾ØÕóµÄ¶Ë¿ÚºÅ
    Identifier VARCHAR(256), -- Éè±¸±êÊ¶£¨ÐòÁÐºÅ»òÉè±¸###9N###7L###1F####)###3<###5?###.9###2B###%3###(6####0####1####-####/####+####,####I###
*###4D####.####G
#####################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
##########################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
 INTEGER, -- »­Ãæ·Ö¸îÀàÐÍ
    XPos INTEGER, -- Êä³öXÎ»ÖÃ
    YPos INTEGER, -- Êä³öYÎ»ÖÃ
    Width INTEGER, -- ¿í¶È
    Height INTEGER, -- ¸ß¶È
    GlobNum    INTEGER,-----Êä³öÍ¨µÀµÄÈ«¾Ö±àºÅ
    LocalNum   INTEGER,-----Êä³öÍ¨µÀµÄ¾Ö²¿±àºÅ
    BackGroundLsh INTEGER DEFAULT -1, -------½âÂëÊä³öÊôÓÚÄ³Ò»¸ö±³¾°µÄÁ÷Ë®ºÅ
    ScreenType    INTEGER DEFAULT 1,   -------½âÂëÊä³öÀàÐÍ£¬1µçÊÓÇ½£¬2´óÆÁ£¬3×ÓÆÁµÈ 
    EnableWnd   INTEGER DEFAULT 1,   -------¿ÉÓÃ×Ó´°¿ÚÊýÁ¿ 
    nRes1 INTEGER default 0, 
    nRes2 INTEGER default 0,        
    nRes3 INTEGER default 0, 
    nRes4 INTEGER default 0, 
    nRes5 INTEGER default 0,   
    CONSTRAINT PK_DecoderOutput PRIMARY KEY (LSH ASC) -- LSHÖ÷¼ü
    )#################################################################################################################
###################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
    Identifier VARCHAR(256), -- ½âÂëÉè±¸±êÊ¶£¨ÐòÁÐºÅ»òÉè±¸Ãû£©
    IPServerAddr VARCHAR(64), -- IPServerµÄIPµØÖ·»òÓòÃû
    LoginType INTEGER, -- ×¢²á·½Ê½£¨IP¡¢ÆÕÍ¨ÓòÃû/Ë½ÓÐÓòÃû£©
    BNCOutputNum INTEGER, -- BNCÊä³öÊý
    VGAOutputNum INTEGER, -- VGAÊä³öÊý
    HDMIOutputNum INTEGER, -- HDMIÊä³öÊý
    DVIOutputNum INTEGER, -- DVIÊä³öÊý
    DecodingResolution INTEGER, -- ½âÂë·Ö±æÂÊ
    Lsh_Matrix INTEGER,-----½âÂë×ÓÏµÍ³µÄ¾ØÕóÁ÷Ë®ºÅ
    SubSysType INTEGER,-----½âÂë×ÓÏµÍ³ÀàÐÍ£¬¸ßÇå»ò±êÇå
    SlotNum    INTEGER,-----×ÓÏµÍ³²ÛÎ»ºÅ
    GuardState INTEGER,-----²¼·À×´Ì¬
    DeviceMask VARCHAR(64),-----×ÓÏµÍ³ÑÚÂë
    GateWay VARCHAR(64),-----Íø¹ØµØÖ·
    DomainName VARCHAR(64),-----ÓòÃûµÇÂ¼Ê±µÄÓòÃûµØÖ·
    DNSAddress VARCHAR(64),-----DNSµÇÂ¼µÄµØÖ·
    Cameras    INTEGER,  -----¸Ã×ÓÏµÍ³°üº¬µÄÍ¨µÀÊýÄ¿
    CameraStart INTEGER, -----ÆðÊ¼Í¨µÀºÅ
    IDForLoginIPServer VARCHAR(256), -- µÇÂ¼IPServerµÄ±êÊ¶£¨ÐòÁÐºÅ»òÉè±¸Ãû£©
    ServerPort INTEGER,--·þÎñÆ÷¶Ë¿Ú 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Decoder PRIMARY KEY (LSH ASC) -- LSHÖ÷¼ü
    )
 -- ½âÂëÉè±¸ÓÃ»§Ãû
    UserPwd VARCHAR(64), -- ½âÂëÉè±¸ÓÃ»§ÃÜÂë
    Port INTEGER, -- ¶Ë¿ÚºÅ###"
###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
 -- Á÷Ë®ºÅ
    BeginTime DATETIME, -- Â¼Ïñ¿ªÊ¼Ê±¼ä
    EndTime DATETIME, -- Â¼Ïñ½áÊøÊ±¼ä
    RecordType INTEGER, -- Â¼ÏñÀàÐÍ£¬0.¼Æ»®Â¼Ïñ£¬1.ÊÂ¼þÂ¼Ïñ£¬2.ÃüÁî£¬3.ÒÆ¶¯Õì²â£¬4.ÕÚµ²£¬5.ÐÅºÅÁ¿¶ªÊ§
    RecordScheduleLSH INTEGER, -- Â¼Ïñ¼Æ»®Á÷Ë®ºÅ
    CONSTRAINT PK_RecordSchedule PRIMARY KEY (LSH ASC) -- LSHÖ÷¼ü
    )ˆeB##//#�ytableTInfo_AlarmDeviceTInfo_AlarmDevice*CREATE TABLE TInfo_AlarmDevice(
    Lsh INTEGER primary ke###+
 DELETE ON TMatrix
   BEGIN
        DELETE FROM TInfo_BigScreenInfo WHERE MatrixLsh = old.LSH and DecLsh = 0;
   END„wN##33#‰#tableTInfo_BigScreenInfoTInfo_BigScreenInfo:CREATE TABLE TInfo_BigScreenInfo(
    LSH INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,----´óÆÁÁ÷Ë®ºÅ£¬Ö÷¼ü
    BigScreenName VARCHAR(64),-----´óÆÁÃû³Æ(±£Áô)
    MatrixLsh,    ------´óÆÁ¾ØÕóÁ÷Ë®ºÅ = 0 Ôò±íÊ¾Îª¾ØÕó´óÆÁ
    DecLsh,       ------½âÂëÆ÷Á÷Ë®ºÅ   = 0 Ôò±íÊ¾Îª½âÂëÆ÷´óÆÁ
    BigScreenID,   -----´óÆÁIDºÅ
    BackGroundLsh, -----Î»ÖÃÐÅÏ¢£¬±³¾°Á÷Ë®ºÅ
    XPos,          -----XÎ»ÖÃ£¬´Ó0¿ª�BO##''#‚CtableTInfo_VersionTInfo_Version;CREATE TABLE TInfo_Version(
    DatabaseVersion INTEGER -- Êý¾Ý¿â°æ±¾£¬ÓÃÓÚÐÞ¸Ä±í½á¹¹¡£°æ±¾ÐÅÏ¢£º01 00 00 0000Ö÷°æ±¾ºÅ£¬´Î°æ±¾ºÅ£¬µÚÈýÎ»°æ±¾ £¬µÚËÄÎ»°æ±¾
)
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not data recovery.

Comment: if the password is literally `µÇÂ¼ÃÜÂë` in the database, I'd start by trying 'password' and 'Password'.  Beyond that, how long ago did the previous employee leave?  You could always try getting in touch with them.  Also, if you have the code to hand and can see how the passwords are generated, build a new one with the code and replace the one in the database (after taking a copy of it in case you screw it up)

Comment: Previous employee is unreachable. The default password was 000000 but that does not get anywhere. I understand what you are saying about building a new one, but that is way over my head skill-wise.

Comment: How did you generate this file please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The desktop client for these has an option to import/export configuration.

Comment: Also, I know my formatting is messy, if someone wants the original file I can send it to you.

Comment: If you know the username is, say `monkey`, try running the `strings` command on your `.db` file to see if you can find `monkey` in there and then look for nearby strings that may be the password... `strings data.db | grep -C5 monkey`

Answer (score 0):

Those unreadable strings are just comments.

Anyway, using the `sqlite3` command-line shell in the [sqlite3-tools package](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), you can convert the entire database to text with a command like this:

```
sqlite3 myfile.db ".dump" > myfile.txt
```